# Three.js postprocessing motion blur renders a black screen

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I've made a [codepen showing the issue](https://codepen.io/blaze33/pen/eKgzav). Problem is: a black screen is rendered instead of a rotating cube.

I'm using https://github.com/vanruesc/postprocessing on top of three.js.

The core postprocessing code is the following:

```
const composer = new POSTPROCESSING.EffectComposer(renderer)
const renderPass = new POSTPROCESSING.RenderPass(scene, camera)
renderPass.renderToScreen = false
composer.addPass(renderPass)

const renderTargetParameters = { format: THREE.RGBAFormat, stencilBuffer: true }
const renderTarget2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, renderTargetParameters)
const effectSaveTarget = new POSTPROCESSING.SavePass(renderTarget2)
effectSaveTarget.clear = false

// motion blur
const effectBlend = new POSTPROCESSING.ShaderPass(THREE.BlendShader, 'tDiffuse1')
effectBlend.material.uniforms[ 'tDiffuse2' ].value = effectSaveTarget.renderTarget
effectBlend.material.uniforms[ 'mixRatio' ].value = 0.0
effectBlend.material.needsUpdate = true
effectSaveTarget.renderToScreen = false
effectBlend.renderToScreen = true
console.log(effectBlend)

composer.addPass(effectBlend)
composer.addPass(effectSaveTarget)
```

Then in the main render loop I just put `composer.render(delta)`

Answer (score 1):

The three.js discourse forum provided me with a solution ubsing vanilla three.js:

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/trying-to-do-simple-motion-blur-but-only-get-a-black-screen/3076

https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/6731/

I think my mistake was to provide a shader object to the ShaderPass while a ShaderMaterial was expected.

```
// post processing starts here

composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );

// render pass

var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera )

// save pass

var renderTargetParameters = {
    minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    stencilBuffer: false
};

var savePass = new THREE.SavePass( new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, renderTargetParameters ) );

// blend pass

var blendPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.BlendShader, 'tDiffuse1' );
blendPass.uniforms[ 'tDiffuse2' ].value = savePass.renderTarget.texture;
blendPass.uniforms[ 'mixRatio' ].value = 0.65;

// output pass

var outputPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
outputPass.renderToScreen = true;

// setup pass chain

composer.addPass( renderPass );
composer.addPass( blendPass );
composer.addPass( savePass );
composer.addPass( outputPass );
```

Comment: Since then I've done a better motion blur shader than the simple 2 frames blending shown here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/simple-motion-blur-effect/3107